# What's the Flutter Binding's initialization order and why?

Tags: flutter

Flutter's runApp implementation:

```
void runApp(Widget app) {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()
    ..scheduleAttachRootWidget(app)
    ..scheduleWarmUpFrame();
}
```

runApp call `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()`, which will call `Binding`'s `initInstance` method:

```
/// A concrete binding for applications based on the Widgets framework.
///
/// This is the glue that binds the framework to the Flutter engine.
class WidgetsFlutterBinding extends BindingBase with GestureBinding, SchedulerBinding, ServicesBinding, PaintingBinding, SemanticsBinding, RendererBinding, WidgetsBinding {

  /// Returns an instance of the [WidgetsBinding], creating and
  /// initializing it if necessary. If one is created, it will be a
  /// [WidgetsFlutterBinding]. If one was previously initialized, then
  /// it will at least implement [WidgetsBinding].
  ///
  /// You only need to call this method if you need the binding to be
  /// initialized before calling [runApp].
  ///
  /// In the `flutter_test` framework, [testWidgets] initializes the
  /// binding instance to a [TestWidgetsFlutterBinding], not a
  /// [WidgetsFlutterBinding].
  static WidgetsBinding ensureInitialized() {
    if (WidgetsBinding.instance == null)
      WidgetsFlutterBinding();
    return WidgetsBinding.instance!;
  }
}
```

Bindings include: GestureBinding, SchedulerBinding, ServicesBinding, PaintingBinding, SemanticsBinding, RendererBinding, WidgetsBinding.

Can anyone explain the `Binding`'s initialization order and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: init call sequence]

As picture showed above, the initialization order is `GestureBinding`-> `SchedulerBinding` -> `ServicesBinding` -> `PaintingBinding` -> `SemanticsBinding` -> `RendererBinding` -> `WidgetsBinding`, which matches the `mixin` order in `WidgetsFlutterBinding`.

Why `BindingBase`'s initInstance() call `WidgetsBinding`'s initInstance() first?

Because in the `mixin` list, `WidgetsBinding` is `most specific`, which is in the last palce（the mixin order matters）.

Check [Dart: What are mixins?](https://medium.com/flutter-community/dart-what-are-mixins-3a72344011f3) for more `mixin` info.